# Upper triangular matrix code to lower triangular

Tags: python

I have a piece of code as follows to create an upper triangular matrix from a random N by N matrix for a given value of N and was just wondering if I could make changes to the ranges etc to allow it to give a lower triangular matrix or if I would just have to write a new piece of code altogether?

```
N = 3
A = np.random.rand(N, N)
for row in range(0, N-1):
    for i in range(row+1, n):
        factor = A[i, row] / A[row, row]
        for j in range(row, n):
            A[i, j] = A[i, j] - factor * A[row, j]
print(A)
```

Comment: Depends on what you actually in the triangular matrix, but a simple `A = A.T` might do ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can alter the given code.  Think of the mathematical underpinnings of this.  What defines "upper triangular"?  The critical property is that for every non-zero entry `A[i, j]`, you have `i <= j`.

To make this generate a lower triangle, you need to invert that logic, such that you're working with `i >= j`.  Try switching your indices into `A`; where does that get you?

Try writing that alteration.  *That* is the effort we would like to see as you next question posted.  Better yet, *not* see it posted, because you get it working without needing us.